# boost thread notify_all() and sleep()

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
boost::condition_variable cond;
boost::mutex mut;
bool ready = false;

void consumer() {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut);
    while (!ready) {
         cond.wait(lock);
    }
}

void producer() {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut);
    ready = true;
    cond.notify_all();
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(4));
}
```

Refer to the above code, I actually sleep the producer thread for 4 seconds after I call notify_all(). However, the consumer threads are actually woken up after 4 seconds. So how can I get around this and wake up the consumer threads immediately after I call notify_all() despite the 4 seconds sleep. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with the boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut); in producer.
As the scope ends AFTER the sleep, the mutex is only released after it.

Try with that, if you want to keep your scoped_lock.

```
void producer() {
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut);
    ready = true;
    cond.notify_all();
  }
  boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(4));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, so if what other locks can I use to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The scoped lock will only be released once the function scope ends. Since your consumers actually need to reacquire the lock before they can continue execution, they will be blocked until the producer releases the lock, even though you notified them to wake up.

Either use the solution proposed by @Clement to reduce the lock scope, or use a different type of lock that you can unlock manually.