# How to delay a function call until a global variable gets set

Tags: c++, synchronization, delay

I'm trying to execute a function, only after my global bool flag gets set to true. I'm currently parsing a file with instructions. Two of the commands are attack and testIsZOmbie.

```
void NAttack::CodeGen(CodeContext& context)
{
    if(flag == true)
    {
      context.m_Ops.push_back("attack ");
    }   
}
```

The problem is that the flag only gets set after my NisZombie::CodeGen function, which always gets called after NAttack....Is there any way to delay NAttack being called until NisZOmbie?

```
void NisZombie::CodeGen(CodeContext& context)
{
  if (m_Dir->m_value == 1)
  {
    context.m_Ops.push_back("test_zombie,1");
    //std::cout<<"HERE";
    context.m_Ops.push_back("je, ");
    flag = true;
   }

}
```

Comment: you can implement [consumer/producer][1] using boost, pthread or win32 sync objects


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11449044/1417782

Comment: What is calling these functions?

Comment: I am using Bison to create a compiler...I have a set of instructions that like rotate, test, forward...Each time one of those words come up they get added to a vector. I reached a problem here because it's a if/else statement. If test == true jump to the line where the "if statement would be if it were true" otherwise just keep going down the list...